# non-solvable finite group with a certain character degrees

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any non-solvable finite group $G$ such that ${\rm cd}(G) =\{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10 \}$, where ${\rm cd}(G)$ is the  set of irreducible character degrees  of $G$. In other words we have that a normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $G/M \cong A_5$. Now, how do we can construct a  non-solvable finite group $G$ such that ${\rm cd}(G) =\{ 1, 3, 4, 5, a, b\}$ where $6$ divides $a$, $10$ divides  $b$, and  $(5, a)=(3,b)=1$ ?

Comment: I don't understand why the first sentence implies the second sentence

Comment: The first sentence is a special case of the second. In other words, the relation between the degrees are important.

Comment: It is certainly not a special case of the second: suppose I take $G= M \times A_5$ where $M$ is non-abelian

Comment: It is not true that ${\rm cd}(A_5) = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,10\}$. So the sentence beginning "In other words" is not true.

Comment: I would like to find a non-solvable finite group G such that  it has exactly six irreducible character and  {1, 3, 4 , 5} is contained in cd(G), and about the other two degrees a, b in cd(G), I know that 6 divides a, 10 divides b , but 5 does not divides a and 3 does not divide b. Since the smallest positive integers with these condition are 6 and 10, I choose the first set as character degree set.

Comment: But then doesn't $|G| = 1^{2} + 3^{2} + 4^{2} + 5^{2} + 6^{2} + 10^{2} = 187$ make that impossible, since all groups of order $187 = 11 \cdot 17$ are cyclic?

Comment: @DavidLHarden this is the set of irreducible character degrees but my understanding is that it ignores multiplicities.

Comment: "exactly six irreducible character" indicates otherwise.

Comment: Also,  when I was working with simple group G/M, I got some possibility for cd(G), but I am not sure that occurs.

Comment: @ DavidHarden. I am Sorry. I mean the size of cd(G) is six.